# receive data from Json array in Json array Android Java

Tags: java, android, json

how to get data from Json Array in another Json array ,i need to get the array "addon items"
and put it in another recycle view

please look at the json and the java code what i already write .

**json output:**

```
[{
    "name": "BOILED EGGS",
    "price": 40000,
    "quantity": 1,
    "option": null,
    "addon items": [
        {
            "addon_item_name": "Cheese",
            "addon_id": "112",
            "price": "2500",
            "quantity": "1"
        }
    ],
    "order notes": "extra meal"
}{
    "name": "Amazon Green Salad",
    "price": 54000,
    "quantity": 1,
    "option": "Full Portion",
    "addon items": [
        {
            "addon_item_name": "Cheese",
            "addon_id": "112",
            "price": "2500",
            "quantity": "1"
        },
        {
            "addon_item_name": "Smoked Salmon",
            "addon_id": "136",
            "price": "4000",
            "quantity": "1"
        }
    ],
    "order notes": ""
}{
    "address": {
        "address": "hadath",
        "flat": "mona bldg",
        "city": "beirut",
        "postcode": "1003"
    },
    "phone": "71883419"
}]
```

please before tell me if i have any problem in this json

**php script :**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
function getAdd($ids) {
      $servername = 'mysql';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$database = '';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id = ? AND meta_key =  '_rpress_delivery_address' ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$ids);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($meta_value);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $arr = unserialize($meta_value);
  return $arr;


}
    
    
}



function getVar($ids,$price) {
    $servername = 'mysql';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$database = '';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id = ? AND meta_key =  'rpress_variable_prices' ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$ids);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($meta_value);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $arr = unserialize($meta_value);

for ($i=0; $i<=count($arr);$i++) {


      $p1 = $arr[$i][amount]+0;
      
      if ($p1 == $price) {
          
          return $arr[$i][name];
      }
   
    }

}

    

}



 
 
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

$id= $_GET['id'];
$servername = 'mysql';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$database = '';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    $orders = array();

$sql = "SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($meta_value);
while($stmt->fetch()){

$arr = unserialize($meta_value);
//var_dump($arr);

for($i=0;$i<=count($arr);$i++) {
$items = array();


$items[$i] =  $arr[cart_details][$i];

if ($items[$i] !== null) {

    $variable_id  = $arr[cart_details][$i][id];
   $vp = $arr[cart_details][$i][price];
   $phone =  $arr[phone];
   $notes = $arr[cart_details][$i][instruction];
  ;

   

//echo $arr[1];
 

$temp = [
    'name' => $arr[cart_details][$i][name],
    'price' => $arr[cart_details][$i][price],
        'quantity' => $arr[cart_details][$i][quantity],
                'option' =>  getVar($variable_id,$vp),
        'addon items'=> $arr[cart_details][$i][addon_items],
                'order notes' => $notes,
                'address' => getAdd($id),
                'phone' => $phone

       
 ];
   
  

    $json = json_encode($temp);
    echo $json;
          
}

}

$fixed_temp = [
    
          'address' => getAdd($id),
        'phone' => $phone
    
    
    ];
    
    

//print_r($arr[cart_details][$i][addon_items]);



}
  // echo json_encode($fixed_temp); 

}



?>
```

please if you see any problem in the php script tell me

**java :**

```
public void getAllPosts() throws Exception{
        String TAG = "POSTS_VIDEO";
        String url = "https://fitness-diner.com/api/api-get-post-data-bkp.php?id="+id;
        StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("response_VIDEO", response);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                parseJson(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                try {

                  //  swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    Log.e("error", "" +error.getMessage());
                }catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                   // swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });


        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, TAG);

    }
    public void parseJson(String response){

        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
            JSONObject jsonObject =null;

            post_array.clear();
            ItemOrder p;
            AddOnitem r;
            for(int i=0 ; i<array.length() ; i++)
            {
                jsonObject=array.getJSONObject(i);


                String nameitem = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String priceitem = jsonObject.getString("price");
                String quantityitem = jsonObject.getString("quantity");
                String optionitem = jsonObject.getString("option");
                //   String addonid = jsonObject.getString("addon items");
                String noteitem = jsonObject.getString("order notes");



                p = new ItemOrder();
                p.setNameitem(nameitem);
                p.setPriceitem(priceitem);
                p.setQuantityitem(quantityitem);
                p.setOptionitem(optionitem);
                p.setNoteitem(noteitem);
                //  p.setViews_video(views_video);


                post_array.add(p);
                //realmHelper.save(p);
            }


        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
           // swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        adapter = new ItemOrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), post_array,id);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

       // swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }
```

i need to solve it quicly

thanks!!

Comment: Your JSON array is not a valid array (there are no commas between objects)

Comment: please tell me what i can change in the php script

Comment: For starters, `temp` is always only one item and you should not echo multiple objects within a loop. You should make an empty array **before** the loop. Append objects to it within the loop, then echo the `json_encode` result of the array once after the loop